# Scheduling the apex Batch jobs?

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

Suppose if i have two batch apex batch jobs 1,2.
 here i scheduled batch job 1 but not 2.
 after Batch1 completing immediately Batchjob2 will be
executed how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45836/find-apex-batch-status-programmatically) of this post. Please refer to existing posts and search SFSE before posting new questions, as there might already be an existing and approved solution to your problem similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your second batch by calling it from the finish method of your first batch class. Take a look at the following example:

```
global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    //start method logic here
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    //start method logic here
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   //call next batch
   SecondBatch mySecondBatch = new SecondBatch();
   Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(mySecondBatch);
   //finish method logic here
}
```

Also take a read of both links, some pretty useful info for batch chaining.

1. [Link 1](https://andyinthecloud.com/2012/10/14/winter13-chaining-batch-jobs-with-great-power/)
2. [Link 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87776/apex-batch-job-chaining-limits)